# Curl login Joomla 1.6/3.0

Tags: php, curl, joomla

I am trying to login Joomla 1.6/3.0 by curl in PHP but not success.

I had try method from joomla 1.5

```
$uname = "id";
$upswd = "pswd";
$url = "http://www.somewebpage.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, './cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, './cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
if (!preg_match('/name="([a-zA-z0-9]{32})"/', $ret, $spoof)) {
    preg_match("/name='([a-zA-z0-9]{32})'/", $ret, $spoof);
}

// POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['username'] = urlencode($uname);
$postfields['passwd'] = urlencode($upswd);
$postfields['lang'] = '';
$postfields['option'] = 'com_login';
$postfields['task'] = 'login';
$postfields[$spoof[1]] = '1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

But it 's show forbidden

Comment: I'm struggling with the same challenge - did you find any solution for yours?

Comment: No, because it use session token. You can do it if you can read and send the token

Answer (score 1):

Joomla! normally from the web browser will send a token, to make sure the form was posted from a browser (and not from somewhere outside, like you are trying to do).

If it's not posted from a browser, an error like 'The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again.'

You may want to look for an autentication plugin that supports what you are trying to do. For example the [Autologin plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/10508).

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve my problem, because that site not mine. I only want independent PHP code.